# Python : circular nested classes with static typing

Tags: python, oop

I use 2 classes to manage emails:

1. one `MailServer` to handle the mail server itself (host, login, etc.)
2. one `EMail` to store the parsed data from each email.

The `MailServer` class has a member which stores the `n` latest emails as a list of `EMail` objects. The `EMail` class has a reference to the parent MailServer such that we can call server operations (move, delete) within the scope of `Email` through proxy methods.

```py
class EMail(object):
  def delete(self):
    self.mailserver.delete_email(self.uid)

  def __init__(self, email_content:bytes, mailserver):
    self.mailserver = mailserver

    #… parse email content, set self.uid



class MailServer(object):
  def delete_email(self, email_uid:int):
    # Delete email from server by uid
    
  def __init__(self, host, login, password):
    # … connect, login into a server, fetch emails

    self.emails = []
    for email in email_queue:
      self.emails.append(EMail(email_content, self))
```

I found this logic allows for efficient implementation, since everything is handled from the `EMail` instance through proxy methods that take care of dispatching the relevant data from emails (flags, IDs, etc.) when calling the underlying server operations.

But I'm a big fan of static typesetting introduced in Python 3.6 for I have lost too many hours troubleshooting edge effects of implicit type casting in Python, and now they also enable auto-completion features in IDE.

So I would like to statically set the type of the `mailserver:MailServer` in the arguments of `EMail.__init__()`. But of course, it yields a `NameError: name 'MailServer' is not defined` if I do that.

C/C++ have a way to prototype objects ahead of declaring them, is there a similar mechanism in Python ?

Comment: Use `'MailServer'` as the type annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have right now, from a static typing perspective, is two classes that have a *strong* dependency on each other. An `EMail` cannot exist without a `MailServer` and a `MailServer` cannot exist without knowing what an `EMail` is. With that tight coupling, you either need to define the classes in the same module or break the dependency.

If the classes are in the same module, then the [`annotations` future import](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) will save you. Assuming you're on Python 3.7 or newer, you can put

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

at the top of your file (above all of your other imports), and then types which refer to things defined *later* in the file will be accepted by type checkers and the Python runtime alike.

*However,* this sort of tight coupling is often a sign of brittle design. So if you want to break this dependency, or if your classes are defined in different files from each other, you'll want to look into [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Basically, ask yourself the following two questions:

1. Is there a situation in which a `MailServer` could function with some other implementation of the `EMail` class?
2. Is there a situation where this `EMail` class could work without a mail server?

Given that you're attached to your proxy method implementation, I'm assuming the answer to (2), at least in your current coding style, is "no". However, I think you could make the `MailServer` type abstract.

Consider having `MailServer` be abstracted over the type of emails. Something like (just a mock-up, intended to be expanded for your use case),

```
class MessageLike(object):
  ...

class EMail(MessageLike):
  ...

_MessageType = TypeVar(bound=MessageLike)

class MailServer(Generic[_MessageType]):
  emails: List[_MessageType]

class EMailServer(MailServer[EMail]):
  ...
```

Now we have the following dependencies:

- `EMailServer` depends on `MailServer` and `EMail`
- `MailServer` depends on the generic type `MessageLike`
- `EMail` depends on `MessageLike` as well, and presumably depends on `MailServer` in your proxy methods (but *not* on `EMailServer`, it should work with *any* `MailServer[EMail]`)
- `MessageLike` depends on none of the others

No cycles whatsoever, and our implementation is more generic.

Comment: `MailServer` is only tied to `Email`, but they are part of a more general Server/Content logic like Agenda/Event, Address book/Contact etc. The abstraction you propose is very elegant but how is the reference between EMail and EmailServer managed then ?